# Integration test is unable to connect to Postgres 9.6 Db in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, database-connection, postgresql-9.6

**Description:**
A .Net Core 3.1 Web API project contains an `IHostedService`-implementing service which reads cache data from PostgresDB in `StartAsync` method. This cache-retrieving service has been registered in `Startup`'s `ConfigureServices` method

**Problem:**
While running integration tests in Jenkins I've found that exception is being thrown while trying to connect to the Db:

```
[19:49:34 ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'FooDb' on server 'tcp://localhost:5432'.
[19:49:34 INF] A transient exception has been encountered during execution and the operation will be retried after 0ms.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
```

This issue is limited to integration tests run, e.g. the service works fine in other scenarios.

**What have I tried so far?**

1. As per MSDN suggestion I've moved the registration of my cache reading service to `Program.cs CreateHostBuilder` method;
2. Refactored cache retrieval to `IStartupFilter` implementation
   none of these steps helped.

Also, I've removed the cache reading service's registration to confirm that its invocation is causing the issue. Indeed, everything works fine if I don't add the cache reading service.

Comment: Just to make sure: Jenkins is running on the same machine as when you have it successfully run, the machine running posgres?

Comment: @shox Thanks for your interest. Yes, this is the case - they run on the same machine as in working scenario

Comment: And jenkins is running bare on the machine not within docker? Have you tried the local IP (e.g. 192.169.x.x, 10.0.x.x) rather than localhost?